# How to achieve this UI using flutter, Image below

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image: UI Required]

I was wondering how I could create this UI in flutter.
This Indicated the progress of a task.

Probable Options are:

1. Use a already available package
2. Hard Code using Containers ( Least Prefered )
3. Slider or Progress Bar Indicator

Note:
The progress bar should be able to show progress at all three values (Which I will provide it while building).
Please share code and tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**timeline_tile**](https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile) package.

The horizontal timeline should be exactly what you need

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).